# How to use the same jquery script twice on a same page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, reusability

I am a novice in JQuery and the problem that I am facing is as follows:

I made a slider base with carouFredSel.

When I use 1 slider in one page, it works perfectly.
But when I use 2 sliders on the same page, it gets messed up (i.e. 1 slider works normally but the other slider does not work.)

The relevant code is as follows:

```
<script>
    if ($('#carmod17').length) {
        $('#carmod17').carouFredSel({
            responsive: true,
            pagination: "#fooitemcatcar2",
            prev: '#prevmod17',
            next: '#nextmod17',
            auto: true,
            scroll: {
                duration: 1500,
                pauseOnHover: true
            },
            items: {
                height: 'variable',
                visible: {
                    min: 1,
                    max: 1
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I do know that the ID must be unique, but how do I dynamically create an unique ID?

Would really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: IDs must be unique. check if you have duplicate IDs.

Comment: *"the slider mess up"* isn't a proper problem description ... it's very meaningless to us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common approach to initializing a plugin on multiple elements where the options are dependent on the instance is to loop over them with an `each` loop so the instances are isolated inside the loop.

Use common classes on the main slider element , buttons and pagers like `slider` , `prev` and `next` and `pager`

```
$('.slider').each(function(){

   // instance specific elements needed for plugin
   var $slider = $(this), 
       $prev = $slider.find('.prev'),
       $pager=  $slider.find('.pager'),
       $next = $slider.find('.next');

   //initialize instance
   $slider.carouFredSel({
            responsive: true,
            pagination: $pager,
            prev: $prev,
            next: $next,
            auto: true,
            scroll: {
                duration: 1500,
                pauseOnHover: true
            },
            items: {
                height: 'variable',
                visible: {
                    min: 1,
                    max: 1
                }
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. All the image show up and no slider function. I can not see #carmod17 selector on your code you gave.

Comment: Did you put the classes on the elements?

Comment: Sorry, not give a class yet. Will try. Thank you.

Comment: It's work for both first and second slider, but the navigation not wok. prev: '#prevmod17', next: '#nextmod17',

Comment: but that's not how the code is in my answer. You need classes on the buttons also

Comment: Just realized need a class for pagination element too...updated my answer

Comment: Have a link I can see it?

Comment: I am sorry, I am working on local host. Not upload yet

Comment: You didn't even attempt to use my solution for instance specific elements

Answer (score 0):

`ID` has to be unique in the DOM.

Use a class instead to initialize the slider.

```
`$('.slider')`   // Make sure you add the className to the element to which you want
               // to attach the slider
```

Also why do you need a dynamic ID, if the use case is to only use to attach a slider to the element.

In the case above you might have an element

```
<div id="carmod17"
```

to which you are attaching the slider and it works perfectly.

Now when the second element comes in you might have added one more element

```
 // Slider 1
 <div id="carmod17"

 // Slider =2
 <div id="carmod17"
```

Now when you try to attach it `$('#carmod17').carouFredSel({` it is only assigned to the first element with that id. So add a `class` to the element and use that class to attach the same.

// Slider 1

```
 // Slider =2
 <div id="carmod17" class="slider"
```

Now you would just use

`$('.slider').carouFredSel({` and both of them should work as expected.

Comment: sorry, I am a newby. How can I do that? Really appreciate for any direction. No need a dynamic ID, just edit the title.

Comment: It's work for both first and second slider, but the navigation not wok.             prev: '#prevmod17',
            next: '#nextmod17',